# Asynchronus call not working with Callback() in code

Tags: callback, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

asynchronus call not working with Callback() , the program waits for the send() to complete and does not execute the next line immidiately. 
in code ,

```java
ProducerRecord<Long, String> record = new ProducerRecord<Long, String>(TOPIC, text);
...
    producer.send(record,new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
            logger.info("sent to kafka");
        }
    });
    logger.info("ACEEVNTMNGR: i am not waiting for the return");
...
```

The code does not execute the next line but executes it only after the connection timeouts and "sent to kafka" is displayed. Actually there is problem with connecting to kafka and getting error:

> "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be
>   available."

but i am hoping that because of the Asynchronus call , it should not wait untill timeout , but execute 
`logger.info("ACEEVNTMNGR: i am not waiting for the return");`
before the timeout happens.

Answer (score 0):

`KafkaProducer:send` returns `Future<RecordMetadata>`, but not all work that is performed by `send` function, is wrapped in to the `Future`.

Before sending message metadata have to be available (at first sending they have to be fetched). 
If metadata are not available or can't be fetched `send` will be lasts at least `max.block.ms`. By default it is 60000ms.

In your example you should see: `ACEEVNTMNGR: i am not waiting for the return` after 60 seconds.